# How to add items to a cart in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I made an app with React which is displaying 9 products on the screen. I made a button to add them to a cart and I want to make the app functionally just for demo purpose. I used hooks and I don't know what I did wrong.Here are the errors that I'm receiving:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Products (Products.js:8:1)
```

```
react-dom.development.js:18523 The above error occurred in the <Products> component:

    at Products (http://localhost:3000/main.f01d7322f0afd7419d5f.hot-update.js:30:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40456:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40389:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39198:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44:84)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Here is the full project: https://github.com/burNN11/Project

```
import productItems from './data/Data'

const Products = ({handleAddProduct, productItems}) => {
  console.log(productItems)
  return (
    <div className='produse'>
      {productItems.map((item)=> (
        <div className='produs' key={item.id}>
          <div>
            <img className='imagine-produs'
              src={item.image} 
              alt = {item.name}
```

Comment: Please note that the `hook` tag specifically says to use `react-hook` when asking about react hooks -> "For React hooks use tag[react-hooks]."

Comment: Also, you need to post a minimal but complete example of your code here as formatted text along with the exact text of the error messages. Images can be nice, but the text should be searchable, copy/paste-able, etc. Also, off-site links can go dead or the content may change, invalidating the question itself.

Comment: I edit the question now.

Comment: You don't show your `Products` component, but it looks like it is not handling a case where data is not available yet (if you expect an array but instead have `undefined` and try to `.map`, this is the exact error you would see.

Comment: you have this `alt = {productItems.name}` in Products, should be `alt = {item.name}` and might also do this `{productItems && productItems?.map((item)=> (...` it maps only when productItems is true (ready)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

I cloned your project, applied my fix and got it to work. The offending code is in `App.js`, in the `handleAddProduct()` handler:

```
const handleAddProduct = product => {
    const ProductExist = cartItems.find(item => item.id === product.id);
    if (ProductExist) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map(item =>
          item.id === product.id
            ? { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity + 1 }
            : item
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { 
        ...product, 
        quantity: ProductExist.quantity + 1  // <-- error is here
      }]);
    }
  };
```

In the `else` block, `ProductExist` is `undefined`, as the only way to get into the `else` block is for it to be `undefined`. But you try to use `ProductExist.quantity + 1`. It should be just `1`, like this:

```
const handleAddProduct = product => {
    const ProductExist = cartItems.find(item => item.id === product.id);
    if (ProductExist) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map(item =>
          item.id === product.id
            ? { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity + 1 }
            : item
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { 
        ...product, 
        quantity: 1  // <-- Change here
      }]);
    }
  };
```

With this change, the cart feature is working on my machine, on localhost. There is no UI update to show the new items in the cart, but I checked the console and the items are being added correctly, without errors.

Hope this helped.

## Original answer

In `components/Products.js`, you define the `<Products/>` component as:

```js
import productItems from './data/Data'

const Products = ({handleAddProduct, productItems}) => {
  console.log(productItems)
  ...
```

You override the `productItems` import by defining it as a prop. This is because of how JavaScript handles [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). The definition in the function parameters takes precedence.

You should change the lines above to remove the prop, like this:

```js
import productItems from './data/Data'

const Products = ({handleAddProduct}) => {
  console.log(productItems)
  ...
```

You don't pass the `productItems` prop in `App.js`, hence the prop is `undefined` when you try to map over it.

Comment: Thanks. I review the code and I modified but the cart still not working.

Comment: @Daniel if this helped and *changed* what the problem is (i.e. no longer the same line/error), mark this answer as accepted and then, with your new code, ask a new question with the details of what is not working.

Comment: I updated my answer to get your code to a point I deem 'working', but @crashmstr is right and the advice they gave is solid. 

In future, you should define exactly the behaviour you expect from your code, which would make answering your questions easier. No worries though, I understand this was your first question on SO. You'll learn the unspoken rules as you progress. SO also has good notes on how to ask questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask